# Lua C++ development files on Linux (/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llua5.1)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, lua, ld

I am building a C++ application that embeds the Lua scripting engine. I am developing on Linux (Ubuntu).

I have already installed Lua on my dev machine (by imstalling the lua5.1 package). I can run the Lua intepreter succesfully (via the cmd line).

However, when building, I get the following link error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llua5.1

I have searched the Ubuntu forums/package repositories etc but I cannot seem to find the required package. Can anyone help?

PS: I also need to install the development files for tolua++ (I'm not sure which Ubuntu package is the required one either).

I am on Ubuntu 10.0.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the liblua5.1-dev package, and if that does not work compile Lua from sources.

Or you can try -llua instead of -llua5.1.

Comment: Note, I had to build with `g++ main.C -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -llua5.1`. it worked

Answer (score 2):

on Fedora 17 problem fixed:

```
sudo ln /usr/lib/liblua-5.1.so /usr/lib/liblua5.1.so
```

Answer (score 0):

For tolua++, it looks like [libtolua++5.1-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libtolua++5.1-dev) is the package you want.